# Change the Source of an Audio tag in HTML5

Tags: html, html5-audio

I am building a browser songs personalized application. I am in the starting phase of the application where I want to click a button and change the song currently being played by the audio player in HTML5. I wanted to know how can I change the source of the audio. I tried using a ajax call when the button is clicked and then the following commands

```
var audio= document.getElementById("myplayer");
audio.src="E:/My Collection/abcd.mp3";
```

But this doesn't work and the same audio song continues. Can anyone help me with this.    Thank You.

Comment: The big problem with your code is that the browser is not going to let you load a local file like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the list of your audio file in an array.

var audioArr = new Array();
audioArr = ["abc.mp3", "xyz.mp3"];

And, then onclick() of button you can pass index. Eg:
 audio.src = audioArr[index];

I hope this works :)

Comment: Please format your answer according to the StackOverflow standards.

Comment: I m actually new to this platform..next time I will take care of it. Thanks !!

Comment: There's no reason to use `new Array()`. Just do this: `var audioArr = ["abc.mp3", "xyz.mp3"];`

Answer (score 1):

in addition to what Bhavya said about array, add audio.load(); or audio.play(); after changing the src. it would make the audio tag reload.